# new to django, stuck at part 3

Tags: django

I am currently stuck at part 3 of the django tutorial.
polls views.py is ...

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<strong>Welcome to the poll index page!</strong>")
```

polls urls is ...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
                   )
```

mysite urls is ...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
           url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
           url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
          )
```

Every time I run it I get ....

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^polls/
^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Can't seem to figure out what is wrong here, any hints?

Comment: What URL are you browsing to?

Comment: It looks like you're browsing to the root url, which indeed doesn't match anything. You've only defined URLs that start with `'/admin'` or `'/polls'`.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is you are pointing to **localhost:8000** which is not yet defined by you, the routes you defined are **localhost:8000/admin** and **localhost:8000/polls**. Visit those to get your urls working or try to change urls like below to get your polls at the **localhost:8000** itself

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
           url(r'^/$', include('polls.urls')),
           url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
          )
```

Hope it Helps.